# How do find substrings and then replace them with returns of a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, replace

I have a text as follow:

```
var txt = 'my name is: {name} {family}'
```

And now I want to find `{name}` and `{family}` by regex and then call a metho. method is as follow:

```
function method(type} {
   if(type === 'name')
      return 'Ali'
   if(type === 'family')
      return 'Malvandi'
}
```

In other words, I want to find substring that start wiht `{` and end with `}` and then replace them with what the method returns.

How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code you've tried that isn't working if you want debugging help

Comment: is it fixed? {name} and {family}, will this string always be in input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regex to extract the contents of each pair of curly braces, calling `method` upon the captured characters by using the callback argument of `replace`.

```js
var txt = 'my name is: {name} {family}';

function method(type) {
  if (type === 'name')
    return 'Ali'
  if (type === 'family')
    return 'Malvandi'
}

const res = txt.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, (m, r) => method(r));

console.log(res);
```

It's much easier to expand this with more key/value pairs if you use an object:

```js
var txt = 'my name is: {name} {family}';

const replace = {
  name: "Ali",
  family: "Malvandi"
}

function method(type) {
  return replace[type] || "Name";
}

const res = txt.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, (m, r) => method(r));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) method

```
{([^}]+)}
```

[image]

```js
var txt = 'my name is: {name} {family}'

function method(type) {
   if(type === 'name'){
     return 'Ali'
   }
   if(type === 'family'){
      return 'Malvandi'
   }
}

let final = txt.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g,(m,g1) => method(g1))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I want to find substring that start wiht { and end with } and then replace them with what the method returns

Comment: @MortezaMalvandi the answer is doing the same, it is finding `{}` string by `{([^}]+)}` and then replacing the values